Minimal number of steps to split a number to powers of two
Split N
Kulyash is given an integer N. His task is to break N into some number of (integer) powers of 2
TO achieve this, he can perform the following operation several times (possibly, zero):
Choose an integer  X which he already has, and break X into 2 integer parts Y and
Z such that X=Y+Z.
Find the minimum number of operations required by Kulyash to accomplish his task.\
Code:
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int c=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int k=pow(2,i);
            for(int j=i;j<n;j++){
                if(k==n){c=0;}
                else if(k+pow(2,j)==n){
                c+=1;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<c<<"\n";

    }
    // your code goes here

}


I tried by implementing as shown above, the test cases are passing but one test case is not passing due to Time Limit Exceeded. How to reduce the time limit for my code.

google popCount

Don't use floating-point functions - like pow - in integer problems. Use 1 << p instead of pow(2, p).

Don't use pow to compute powers of two, it'll end in tears. To corroborate @MarekR's answer: think about what the binary representation of a number (eg 10010101) actually means in terms of "sum of powers of two"

Side notes: (1) Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>? (2) What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

If n is a sum of positive integers, none of those integers can be larger than n. In particular, checking any pow(2, x) where x is larger than log2(n) is a waste of time.

@OP Advice -- Instead of telling a story about Split N Kulyash, you should simply state what the goal is of your program.  Keeping the question as short and to the point as possible is what you should strive for.

Consider 15 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8. It takes 3 operations to find the terms: Round 1: 15 = 7 + 8. Round 2: 7 = 3 + 4. Round 3: 3 = 1 + 2. Therefore, I expected your program to answer 3. When I ran it, however, I got 0.


The test cases are passing but one test case is not passing due to Time Limit Exceeded. How to reduce the time limit for my code.

Are you sure your program passes all the test cases? When I ran your program for n equals 15, I got the answer 0. I was expecting 3, however, because 15 == 1 + 2 + 4 + 8, which requires three operations:

15 == 7 + 8
7 == 3 + 4
3 == 1 + 2

The program fails for 15, because it searches only for pairs of numbers that add to n. Furthermore, the numbers it searches for must be powers of 2. These are big defects. There is no simple way to modify the algorithm in the OP to extend the search to three or more terms.
Ignoring the fact that it sometimes produces incorrect results, the algorithm in the OP is slow, because is uses two nested loops. The inner loop runs from i to n, so the overall runtime is proportional to O(n*(n-i)). On average, i == n/2, so the average runtime is proportional to O(n*(n/2)). Therefore, the average runtime is O(n²).
In addition, the program in the OP needlessly invokes std::pow, which may be slowing things down a bit, as well.
An alternative algorithm
For n > 0, the number of operations depends on the number of 1-bits in n. Specifically, it is count_one_bits(n) - 1.
When n is 48, for instance, the number of operations is 1, because 48 == 16 + 32, and 48 == 0b110000. When n is 49, the number of operations is 2, because 49 == 1 + 16 + 32, and 49 == 0b110001.
Here is a short program that uses bit-operations to find the number of operations.

Function main uses variable submit_for_evalution to control where input comes from. This allows you to specify your own set of test inputs, rather than relying on the ones from the submission site.

Functions are short, with descriptive, self-documenting names. They follow the guidance given by Sean Parent, in his Better Code series of videos: the correct number of loops in a function is usually 0 or 1.


// main.cpp
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <system_error>

unsigned get_unsigned_int(std::istream& ist) {
    std::string s;
    if (!std::getline(ist, s))
        throw std::runtime_error("get_unsigned_int: `std::getline` failed.");
    unsigned n;
    auto const end{ s.data() + s.size() };
    auto const [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(s.data(), end, n);
    if (ec != std::errc{} || ptr != end)
        throw std::runtime_error("get_unsigned_int: `std::from_chars` failed.");
    return n;
}
int count_one_bits(unsigned n) {
    int count{};
    while (n != 0u) {
        if ((n & 1u) == 1u)
            ++count;
        n >>= 1u;
    }
    return count;
}
void splitN(std::istream& ist, std::ostream& ost) {
    auto t{ get_unsigned_int(ist) };
    while (t--) {
        auto const n{ get_unsigned_int(ist) };
        auto const n_operations{ n == 0u ? 0 : count_one_bits(n) - 1 };
        ost << n_operations << '\n';
    }
}
int main() {
    constexpr bool const submit_for_evaluation{ false };
    if constexpr (submit_for_evaluation)
        splitN(std::cin, std::cout);
    else
    {
        std::istringstream iss{
            "5\n"
            "0\n"
            "1\n"
            "15\n"
            "48\n"
            "49\n"
        };
        splitN(iss, std::cout);
    }
}
// end file: main.cpp

Output
Here is the output from a test run:
0
0
3
1
2

